# How to merge changes back to repository in tortoisesvn

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn

I've started using tortoisesvn for local revision control on my PC and I am a newbie and I think i'm doing something wrong...

I created the a repository for my files /repo/pr01 from its original location /pr01

I created a work directory and then checked out all the files to /work/pr01

I have made changes to a file in /work/pr01 and then right clicked and selected "commit"

When I compare the files (/work/pr01 and /pr01), none of the changes have been copied across from /work/pr01 to /repo/pr01... Am I missing something?  Do I need to manually copy the file across as well as commtting?

THanks

Answer (score -1):

If /repo/pr01 is a working copy, then you would need to `update` that working copy to reflect any changes made to the repository.

There is a big difference between the repository and a working copy.

You won't be able to see any changes to an existing file in a repository by looking unless you open a hex editor, since the changes are stored as diffs. Changes will not auto-propagate to a working copy, the `update` command is needed to pull down changes.

Comment: The repository will _not_ be a location in the file system that has all of the files in the repository stored in a "typical" way. If that is what /repo/pr01 is, and if it has "normal" files in it, then it is _not_ the actual repository. If it has .svn directories in each directory, it is a working copy as well. By default, when you turn an existing file structure into a repository, it turns it into a working copy of the new repository.

Comment: yes but that repository references real files in a real location (/repo/pr01). those real files are then checked out into a working directory (/work/pr01)

Comment: Like I said, the files originally committed to the repository when it was created _become_ a working copy, which then functions _exactly_ like _every other_ working copy. The repository doesn't "reference" the files original. The files' content becomes revision 1, and the content is stored in the repository.

Comment: so I should be uploading files that I checked out to /work/pr01 to the server? Thus making the original files in /repo/pr01 nothing but an original copy, never to be used again?

Comment: I followed this guide http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html but what you saying contrdicts this configuration